# tsc return -1 in multi device hybrid app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, multi-device-hybrid-apps

great idea but,

I just download Visual Studio Ultimate Update 3 and all packets, 
then I install node.js (better 64bit but your link is for 32bit version)
ecc. and Git, which VS continue to said that is not installed,

so after installing all, and then start with typescript project, when I compiling in console appear tsc.exe return -1.

this is my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

> when I compiling in console appear tsc.exe return -1.

Should only happen if you have compile errors. Fixing them should make it `0`